# Import publish profile from Azure web app into Visual Studio Code (or vs for mac)

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-code, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a dotnet 6 web application that currently being hosted in azure.  I recently changed machines and needed to be able to publish changes.  After pulling down my project onto my new machine from the repo I was able to import the publish profile into the new project and continue to publish without issue. (see image below)
[image]

My question is am I able to do something similar in visual studio code? And if so will it work cross platform?  Say if I am using visual studio code on a mac? If it is not possible in vs-code what about visual studio for mac? I am the lone developer on this project and it would be nice to be able to publish from multiple machines (windows pc and macbook) should one of them go down.

I am hoping that I can use the import functionality because I have had very few issues publishing this way.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this feature is not available for vs for mac. However you can achieve this from windows. Here is a tutorial for that[Publish to Azure by importing publish settings - Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2022#import-the-publish-settings-in-visual-studio-and-deploy). Also there is a feature request that is made which is under review, You can follow up here [Provide a mechanism to import Azure Function Profiles exported from Azure Portal](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Provide-a-mechanism-to-import-Azure-Func/1294204?space=41&q=import+publish+profile) for more information.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for vs code and mac specifically.  Appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer (for anyone else who may be looking for this) is to just create a build and release pipeline in azure.  Then it really doesn't matter where or how you develop your application.